# My server mail going junk in hotmail and yahoo

Tags: linux, email, smtp, spam, spam-filter

All my server mails going to spam in hotmail and yahoo. Here is my full mail source. Can any one please help me to sort out this issue ?

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRyU+pBy2R9QCDI9u8Kc1Jen/cHV1gUaS24G4DKF5OyCzEFltdVYxf/U4tC+z+83a3F/1TyfPewdH0QdEYMQ951mB/P/Dw5iT8myYw8K7+zHdz+DroxAfdvg=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 162.144.82.142) smtp.mailfrom=admin@mycompany.com; dkim=pass header.d=mycompany.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=admin@mycompany.com
X-SID-PRA: admin@mycompany.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD00
X-Message-Info: 11chDOWqoTl6HjGE9/H8+/QjhgnGC21ffJDOn7finCyTTlyUaI24NGi3HjF9PjrBnpP3zY0bOifg5AWLM70RH0F+LNUcDBsxVH0/nssTRy8HGIzJUOKwUY4nCWJs/1Oa2Ywkqv/1NjHwNJs+hRHIr0rPcSiWEjCzvtYidS+dRA9tMkNlFUot7ktYDutSn6TzfS/Xlde5FOYPJyqgafnLKWnwHbAQ50cU
Received: from tic.mycompany.com ([162.144.82.142]) by COL004-MC1F19.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23008);
     Mon, 20 Apr 2015 23:10:09 -0700
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mycompany.com; s=default;
    h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:Reply-To:From:To:Date; bh=vyg7nyFcpbqkWqkPyefi/tzDbA0NJc81DZjIqWk7A5c=;
    b=OTeHkTJ0sZZG5Lgx/PUHM/ylmUdwWp8Lp0TiCSEdZoAhbuntVIVxW9tfkznTKQtfdnsH26AouGvk8M3CIweXByvPtqlXADddNrXjR34xObOD+AJI0M/1X6sj2SDaN/06yqtlctDUp3NXrGFCM3uEDp96NpzxCr0EtV9p/p9Dw5s=;
Received: from mycompany.com ([162.144.137.136]:46281 helo=www.mycompany.com)
    by tic.mycompany.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.85)
    (envelope-from <admin@mycompany.com>)
    id 1YkRNo-0007KS-8h
    for mymail@hotmail.com; Tue, 21 Apr 2015 01:10:08 -0500
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 06:10:07 +0000
To: mymail@hotmail.com
From: admin <admin@mycompany.com>
Reply-To: admin <admin@mycompany.com>
Subject: Test mail from code
Message-ID: <961ddc2e972e3ba3c12e509a43179d23@www.mycompany.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - tic.mycompany.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - hotmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mycompany.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: tic.mycompany.com: authenticated_id: admin@mycompany.com
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 
Return-Path: admin@mycompany.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Apr 2015 06:10:09.0403 (UTC) FILETIME=[D1FFF4B0:01D07BF9]

Test mail from code.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Tips to make sure your mail doesn't go to spam:

- Make sure the plain text and html mail contain the same content
- Use [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/)
- Don't use "test" in the body/title (I've noticed from personal experience this does not help your spam score)
- To test, create a new gmail account and see if the message gets into the spambox
- Send real messages when testing, short nonsense messages are much more likely to end up as spam
- If possible, switch the IP address you are sending from.